# Performant method to get triple statistic or count in a Apache Jena Fuseki repository

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I have a requirement where I need to count/estimate number of triples in a repository. At the moment I am using SPARQL query to count number of triples in a repository but this is slowing down as size is growing. Is there any better way to get the same information without executing query? I was wondering if it possible to get estimate? My thinking is that under the hood query planner might have this information. So one possibility could be to write an extension function or custom plugin to get the stat from planner.

Will really appreciate if anyone can give idea about the performant way to get number/estimate of triples in a repository. I do not need filtering. All I need is total number of triples. Even estimate will be fine as long as it is not too far off from the actual number of triples.

Comment: depending on how often your dataset is changing you could simply keep track of it via adding/updating the size inside the graph itself via a simple RDF triple. Like using [VOID vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/) and adding e.g. `void:triples 100` to a graph

Comment: *"Is there any better way to get the same information without executing query?"* Fuseki uses the same query in dataset info. It is said that *"this may be slow and impose a significant load on large datasets"*.

Comment: *"I was wondering if it possible to get estimate"*. If your data are typed and shaped, then try something like this: `SELECT ?triples { { SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?type1) { [] a org:Organization } } { SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?type2) { [] a foaf:Person } } BIND (7*?type1 + 5*?type2 AS ?triples)}`.